# Laravel, save data from array to database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I need to save data from this array to MySQL database

```
0 => {#517 ▼
    +"id": 59
    +"name": "example_name_1"
    +"category": "category_1"
    +"price": 100
    +"description": "example_description_1"
}
1 => {#516 ▼
    +"id": 60
    +"name": "example_name_2"
    +"category": "category_2"
    +"price": 200
    +"description": "example_description_2"
}
```

I am tryinig to save like this, but reveive errors like

> Undefined index: name

```
for ($idx = 0; $idx < count($products); $idx++)
{
    $values = new Product();
    $values->name = $products["name"][$idx];
    $values->category= $products["category"][$idx];
    $values->description = $products['description'][$idx];
    $values->price = $products['price'][$idx];
    $values->save();
}
```

Comment: Dump the variable `products` to understand how to use it. You have to use a `foreach ($products as $product) { $product->name ... }`

Comment: thanks, it works now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get that error because the order you accessed the array is incorrect.

The order should be the which product index and then name, category or whichever field.

```
for ($idx = 0; $idx < count($products); $idx++)
{
    $values = new Product();
    $values->name = $products[$idx]["name"];
    $values->category= $products[$idx]["category"];
    $values->description = $products[$idx]['description'];
    $values->price = $products[$idx]['price'];
    $values->save();
}
```

Or you can easily use a `foreach` as @VincentDecaux mentioned in his comment.

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $values = new Product();
    $values->name = $product["name"];
    $values->category= $product["category"];
    $values->description = $product['description'];
    $values->price = $product['price'];
    $values->save();
}
```